# How to load a saved WebArchive on a WebView

Tags: android, webview, local-storage

I've been trying for days different methods to save a website locally and then load it into a web-view. I've seen some posts that suggests using `saveWebArchive` but I'm not able to recover it once saved.

here is my code:

```
   browser.loadUrl(URL);

    browser.saveWebArchive(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "index");

    browser.loadUrl(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "index");
```

I'm getting an error from the WebView saying that the Webpage is not available.
 Any suggestions?

If you know any other way to save a website into local storage and then recover it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I asked something similar before.

[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364501/how-can-i-load-an-archived-webpage-properly-in-android) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution what works for me.

Use .mht extension:

```
browser.loadUrl(URL);
```

You have to save webarchive in the onPageFinished() method

```
browser.saveWebArchive(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "index.mht");
```

The loading is simple

```
browser.loadUrl(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "index.mht");
```

In kotlin

```
browser.loadUrl(URL);
browser.saveWebArchive("$filesDir/index.mht")
browser.loadUrl("$filesDir/index.mht");
```