# How can I load an archived webpage properly in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, android-webview

I want to save the webpage to local.

I found that there is a method to save the webpage as an archive file.

```
public void saveWebArchive (String filename)
```

However, I got nothing but gibberish when I load the file.

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview_layout);
String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
webView.loadUrl(url);
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "yahoo" + ".html";
webView.saveWebArchive(path);
webView.loadUrl("file://" + path);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've received a lot of good answers on your previous questions but haven't up-voted or accepted any of them. Please do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebArchive is a special file format that isn't directly readable by a `WebView` (even though it's happy to save pages in that format).

If you're trying to save the HTML contents of the page onto your device, there is a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531062/how-to-programmatically-download-an-html-page-in-android-and-get-its-html).

If you really want to save the page as a WebArchive file, try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872043/android-webview-display-webarchive). This approach may be useful if you need to store the graphics, CSS, and other non-text associated with the page.